# Unable to resolve dead simple configuration dependency

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side, appsettings

I am trying to set up dependency injection in a small blazor-based web app.

My current code is:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

AddDeliveryStats(builder.Services, builder.Configuration);

// ...blazor template things...

void AddDeliveryStats(IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager config)
{
    services.Configure<BigQuerySettings>(config.GetSection("BigQuery"));
    services.AddTransient<IBigQueryClient, BigQueryClient>();
    // ...other stuff not pertinent to the error...
}
```

where `BigQuerySettings` is given as

```
public class BigQuerySettings
{
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string DataSetId { get; set; }
    public string AuthFilePath { get; set; }
}
```

and `BigQueryClient` has the following constructor:

```
public BigQueryClient(
    BigQuerySettings bigQuerySettings,
    ILogger<BigQueryClient> logger) { /* ... */ }
```

and my `appsettings.json` contains the following:

```
{
  // ...
  "BigQuery": {
    "ProjectId": "<project-identifier>",
    "DataSetId": "",
    "AuthFilePath": "BigQueryAuthProd.json"
  }
}
```

and if this looks pretty much like a tutorial example, that's because it basically is. It does not work and it is not obvious why. I get the following error:

> Some services are not able to be constructed
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IBigQueryClient Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: BigQueryClient': Unable to resolve service for type 'BigQuerySettings' while attempting to activate 'BigQueryClient'.)

I have copied this code from online tutorial examples and adapted it as appropriate to my own classes, and I have read every piece of documentation I have been able to find (much of which I can't understand) and googled at least ten different permutations of the keywords in the error message. Nothing really points to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Using `services.Configure` means you need to inject an `IOptions` as the dependency. For example: `public BigQueryClient(IOptions<BigQuerySettings> bigQuerySettings...` and inside there you use `bigQuerySettings.Value` to get your instance of `BigQuerySettings`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a call to `services.Configure` will only allow injecting an `IOption<BigQuerySettings>` into your consumers.

If, however, you wish to inject `BigQuerySettings` directly into your consumer (which I would argue [you should](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/servicecollectionintegration.html#working-with-ioptions-t)), you should do the following:

```
BigQuerySettings settings =
    Configuration.GetSection("BigQuery").Get<BigQuerySettings>();

// TODO: Verify settings here (if required)

// Register BigQuerySettings as singleton in the container.
services.AddSingleton<BigQuerySettings>(settings);
```

This allows `BigQuerySettings` to be injected into `BigQueryClient`.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning the `IOptionsMonitor` and `IOptionsSnapshot` also exist and potentially change the validity of injecting the class directly. Granted they are far less often used, but still, it can catch people off guard.

Comment: I would say `IOptionsMonitor` and `IOptionsSnapshot` are a different discussion to `IOptions`, because they actually add (interesting) behavior, where `IOptions` is just a framework-provided wrapper around the settings object, which likely only exists to work around some framework limitation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; however I am not using a `ContainerBuilder`, just plain `ServiceCollection`. I managed to find an equivalent.

Comment: @KileDamgaardAsmussen: I'm sorry, I made a copy/paste error in my answer. You should call `services.AddSingleton`. I updated my answer